# Kafka Streams Integration Testing - Unable to Compile due to Class Package Mismatch - Apache Kafka, KafkaEmbedded

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm trying to compile code for integration test classes found in Confluent GitHub - [GenericAvroIntegrationTest.java](https://github.com/JohnReedLOL/kafka-streams/blob/master/src/test/java/io/confluent/examples/streams/GenericAvroIntegrationTest.java)

I'm getting a compile time exception for one of the classes SecurityProtocol which is currently present in `import org.apache.kafka.common.security.auth.SecurityProtocol;`. When I compile using maven, it is complaining saying the following:

```
[105,82] cannot access org.apache.kafka.common.protocol.SecurityProtocol


class file for org.apache.kafka.common.protocol.SecurityProtocol not found
```

This is used in the [KafkaEmbedded.java](https://github.com/JohnReedLOL/kafka-streams/blob/master/src/test/java/io/confluent/examples/streams/kafka/KafkaEmbedded.java) class. The code on Confluent GitHub uses the `org.apache.kafka.common.protocol.SecurityProtocol` package but the version I'm using has the same class moved to the other package I mentioned: `import org.apache.kafka.common.security.auth.SecurityProtocol`. If I revert back to the version Confluent is using, my code might not work (not sure which dependency version I've got wrong! :( ). How do I resolve this conflict? How do I find where it is wrongly being referred?

Comment: That linked class is not in the Confluent Github

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the POM, you'll see

```
 <kafka.version>0.10.0.0-cp1</kafka.version>
 <confluent.version>3.0.0</confluent.version>
```

Not sure if this helps you because you didn't mention which versions you're using, but that code is not the Confluent Github with the latest code.

Try https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples/blob/5.0.0-post/src/test/java/io/confluent/examples/streams/GenericAvroIntegrationTest.java

Comment: I checked all the versions and they match. Also, I'm referring to the confluent's code. It was maven's issue to not be able to resolve the dependency. I'm past all those errors but now it's not compiling with the error:

` java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: MAP
        at io.confluent.rest.RestConfig.baseConfigDef(RestConfig.java:293)
        at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.SchemaRegistryConfig.baseSchemaRegistryConfigDef(SchemaRegistryConfig.java:326) `

Comment: Not sure what to tell you, but the links in your question are definitely pointing at this guy's repo https://github.com/JohnReedLOL

Comment: Thanks for your response! I figured it had to with versions of the libraries used.